# ¿Como se hace este dominio? es.stackoverflow.com

Tags: url, dominio

hay algo que realmente me está costando encontrar en algún sitio. ¿Como se realiza este tipo de URL? Es decir, si yo quiero hacer una aplicacion web, por ejemplo, ¿Como le pongo el siguiente dominio/url? app.miaplicacion.com

Comment: se llama [subdominio](https://es.godaddy.com/help/anade-un-subdominio-que-apunte-a-una-direccion-ip-4080)

Comment: Todo depende de la tecnología que esté detrás de tu sitio. Es decir, dependerá de tu servidor web. Es diferente hacerlo para IIS que para apache o para nginx, etc.  Te recomiendo [edit] tu pregunta y colocar mayor información de contexto (Revisa [ask]).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para comenzar, aclarar que, en el ejemplo que pones en la pregunta, `app` es simplemente un sub-dominio más de `miaplicacion.com`, tal como lo es `www`, `ftp` o `mail`.

Es decir,

- `www.miaplicacion.com`
- `ftp.miaplicacion.com`
- `app.miaplicacion.com`

Son lo mismo (registros tipo A en el DNS) y se configuran prácticamente igual.

Los pasos a seguir son:

- Debes tener uno o varios servidores, dedicados o compartidos, donde puedas administrar la configuración del `DNS`.
- Compra el dominio `miaplicacion.com` y utiliza la(s) dirección(es) de los servidores `DNS` sobre los que hablamos en el paso anterior como parte del registro de dicho dominio.
- Configura el `DNS` del servidor inicial con lo típico para que resuelva los relacionado al dominino.
- Finalmente, al `DNS` agrega un nuevo registro de tipo `A` para `app.miaplicacion.com.` y que resuelva a la(s) direcciones que tengas previstas para realizar lo que vayas a hacer con el sub-dominio, por ejemplo, en el caso de `es.stackoverflow.com`, lo que hay detrás es servidores web (IIS), que a la fecha de escribir esta publicación están alojadas en 4 IP's distintas:

```
    C:\Users\jachguate>nslookup es.stackoverflow.com
    Server:  midns.mired.net
    Address:  10.3.32.22

    Non-authoritative answer:
    Name:    es.stackoverflow.com
    Addresses:  151.101.193.69
              151.101.65.69
              151.101.1.69
              151.101.129.69
```

- Quizás esté de más, pero no olvidar que en el o los servidores que tengas destinados para prestar el servicio, debe estar configurado para prestarse. Tomando de nuevo el caso de `es.stackoverflow.com`, es un servicio web y en el puerto 443 está a la escucha el ya mencionado `IIS` que es capaz de reconocer la llamada al sub-dominio y ejecutar lo necesario para producir el resultado deseado.
- Vale decir que muchos de esos pasos los resuelves con comprar un típico servicio de *hosting* compartido, solo asegúrate de tener control del DNS de tu dominio.

Comment: En algunos casos se usa `*.dominio.com` es llamado dominio comodin.